# Get value of a custom attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I saw the same questions but i did not get the answer.
the project have a table and in table is two records and each records have a button (with Similar name and id )  i'm add a custom attribute with name `id-account` and first record have `1` value and second record have `2` value.

button (i'm using laravel 5.7) :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id-account="'.$this->id.'" name="edit-bank-account" id="edit-bank-account">edit</a>
```

and i write this code that return value of `id-account` attribute,

```
$('#edit-bank-account').click(function(){        
   console.log( $("#edit-bank-account").attr("id-account"));
});
```

but there is a problem because this code just return value of first record and when i click to second record nothing returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id`s **must** be unique. You need to use `class` for multiple elements.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.edit-bank-account').click(function() {   //Use class edit-bank-account
  console.log($(this).attr("id-account"));   //Use this as selector, this will refer to the clicked element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit-bank-account" id-account="1" name="edit-bank-account" >edit</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit-bank-account" id-account="2" name="edit-bank-account" >edit</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit-bank-account" id-account="3" name="edit-bank-account" >edit</a>
```